# AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'items'

Tags: list, python-3.x

```
import re, time, _thread
import urllib.request
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


def get_data(n):
    global s,r
    html=urllib.request.urlopen('http://www.fmkorea.com/index.php?mid=best&listStyle=webzine&page='+str(n))
    soup=BeautifulSoup(html,'lxml')
    l=soup.findAll('h3', {'class':'title'}) 

    for i in l:
        for j in re.split(r'''\)|\(|\'|\"|\?|\]|\[|,|\.|\ |\:''',i.text[:i.text.rfind('[')].strip()):
            s[j.strip()] = s.get(j.strip(),0) + 1
            r=r+1

    s={}
    r=0

    for _ in range(1,2037):
            _thread.start_new_thread(get_data, (_,))
            time.sleep(0.05)

        while r!=2036:
            time.sleep(3)

    with open('res','w') as f:
        s=sorted(s.items(),key=lambda x: x[1],reverse=True)
        for i in s:
            f.writelines(str(i[0]) + " : " + str(i[1])+"\n")
```

---

```
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-24-3e6cc449e797> in <module>()
     35 # 
     36 with open('res','w') as f:
---> 37     s=sorted(s.items(),key=lambda x: x[1],reverse=True)
     38     for i in s:
     39         f.writelines(str(i[0]) + " : " + str(i[1])+"\n")

AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'items'
```

---

I keep getting this error for the code above and cannot seem to fix it. How do I prevent the `AttributeError` from being raised?

Comment: What is the content of s ? I assume s is a list and not an array/tuple, as the error suggests.

Comment: s is dict......

Comment: The code you posted contains an IndentationError. Because you don't show what `s` really is the error is not verifiable. Please [edit] the question so it can be copy&pasted (so we can also see the exception!). It should only contain the necessary code required to produce the error (so file opening can be completly removed). Please have a look at [mcve] and when you edit the question make sure you provide one.

Comment: I am sorry I made a mistake because it was the first time to ask questions in stackoverflow. It was indentation problem as you said. Thank you for your help.

Comment: Is it possible that you are changing the value of `s` elsewhere in one of your thread? But anyway you should debug the `s` line 36 to be sure it is a `dict`.

Answer (score -1):

items is for dictionaries you cant use it on list

```
>>> d = {1:'a'}
>>> d.items()
dict_items([(1, 'a')])

>>> l = [1,2]
>>> l.items()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'items'
```